# How do you send a data in wordpress on other page which will be used in a Form

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi how can you query in a custom page template , basically I have this two page, one is a form and another is page that has a link (this one has the value I need to pass to the other page) , can you help me , thanks

PAGE1 
has a link like this http://example.com/producDetail?data=1

PAGE 2 
this will capture the data send by page 1
$data = $_GET['data'];

^ the GET query doesnt work in me? I dont know (it must be something?)

Comment: why not just have 1 page do the work? then redirect? Also post your `<form>` code

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest you revise yourquestion a bit to make it not so confusing. Maybe include some code. If i understand you right you should be able to do something like this.

data url:

```
http://example.net/?data=somedata
```

page you need to read the data

```
$data=$_GET['data'];
echo"$data"; //somedata
```

Check that your form post type set to GET not POST?